# Loading an array of videos in two columns in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, contentful, video-embedding

I'm trying to get videos to load two videos per row down the page in order and i'm having trouble figuring out how. Currently I have them loading from contentful in one column with this:

```
const VideoPage = ({ data }) => {
return (
    <div>
        <Layout>
        <Head title="Videos"/>
            <div className={videoStyles.container}>
                {data.allContentfulVideoEmbed.nodes.map((node) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className={videoStyles.videoWrapper}
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.markdownContent.childMarkdownRemark.html }}
                            />
                            <div className={videoStyles.titles}>
                                <p>{node.title}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    </div>
)
}
```

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply throw them into a grid with 2 columns, each looped item will then be placed in corrosponding columns 1 - 2 for each row. For instance with Tailwindcss

```js
const VideoPage = ({ data }) => {
return (
    <div>
        <Layout>
        <Head title="Videos"/>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
                {data.allContentfulVideoEmbed.nodes.map((node) => {
                    return (
                      /**
                        * Every nth 1 will be column 1
                        * Every nth 2 will be column 2
                        */
                        <div>
                            <div className={videoStyles.videoWrapper}
                            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: node.markdownContent.childMarkdownRemark.html }}
                            />
                            <div className={videoStyles.titles}>
                                <p>{node.title}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without tailwind, maybe with styled components or scss?

Comment: Yes of course, tailwind is only an abstraction of css using class names. You would simply just do something like `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`